# STM32F103C8 SPI1 clock frequency too low (~32kHz)

Tags: stm32, spi, frequency

I am trying to program SPI1 on STM32F103C8T6 (black pill board).
I have configured it as follows:

```
enable APB2 IOPA clock in RCC_APB2ENR register
enable APB2 SPI1 clock

configure SPI1 SCK pin as AF_OPENDRAIN, OUTPUT_50MHZ
configure SPI1 MOSI pin as AF_OPENDRAIN, OUTPUT_50MHZ
; no need to read from slave, so MISO not configured

configure SPI_CR1: 11000010 01010100
;1: 1-line bidirectional data mode
;1: Output enabled (transmit-only mode)
;0: CRC calculation disabled
;0: Data phase (no CRC phase)
;0: 8-bit data frame format is selected for transmission/reception
;0: Full duplex (Transmit and receive)
;1: Software slave management enabled
;0: Internal slave select. Has an effect only when the SSM bit is set
;0: MSB transmitted first
;1: Peripheral enabled
;010: fPCLK/8
;1: Master configuration
;0: CK to 0 when idle
;0: The first clock transition is the first data capture edge

configure SPI_CR2: 00000000 00000000
```

As I try to send data, two strange things happens.

0. If I start the Saleae Logic with sample rate 16 MS/s, I get a message box 'we're sorry, but the device was not able to keep up with this sample rate ...', and no data captured.
1. Lowering the sample rate down to 500 kS/s results in data capture, but I can see that the clock frequency is about 32 **k**Hz, not ~8**M**Hz as expected. Changing BR (bits 5:3 in SPI_CR1) brings nothing.

Please some ideas what is here wrong. I have tried to search internet, but it seems that I stay alone with such a problem.

Here is how logic analyser looks like
[image]

The captured bytes are correct. Just as sent.

Comment: If your logic analyser is only sampling at 500kHz, you can't really expect to see an 8MHz SPI clock can you? You're just seeing the aliased result of its undersampling.

Comment: But I can see 8MHz SCK with the same logic analyser while connecting to the same slave with nRF5182. So, I suppose all is correct with my logic analyser.

Comment: What was the sample rate when you were looking at the nRF5182? It certainly wasn't 500kHz...

Comment: Yes, of course it was something definitely higher. Please see the 0th case from my 1st post.

Comment: the documentation for the chip is on the internet.

Comment: you are surely joking : )

Comment: The SPI speed depends on the APB2 clock and the divider configured in SPI_CR1. What clock configuration are you running at? It would seem that the APB2 is 256kHz only.

Answer (score 1):

> If I start the Saleae Logic with sample rate 16 MS/s, I get a message
> box 'we're sorry, but the device was not able to keep up with this
> sample rate ...', and no data captured.
>
> Lowering the sample rate down to 500 kS/s results in data capture, but
> I can see that the clock frequency is about 32 kHz, not ~8MHz as
> expected. Changing BR (bits 5:3 in SPI_CR1) brings nothing.

To capture an 8 MHz square wave, you're going to need a capture rate of at least 16 Msps, preferably higher.

Trying to capture an 8 MHz signal with 500 ksps simply isn't a viable strategy.

Try again with 16ksps and lower the capture duration to fit within the logic analyzer's memory.  Consider using Logic 2.x software instead to see if it'll work better.

Comment: The screenshot from the logic analyzer shows a valid SPI signal at about 32 kHz. For this clock speed, the logic analyzer is working just fine. Fixing the logic analyzer problem will not bring the SPI clock speed up to the desired 8 MHz.